# Navbar Length resizing/fixing(whitespace) when window is minimized

Tags: html, css, angular

When I minimize the window, there's white space at the right hand side of the nav-bar. I didn't use any css.

If anybody can help me with that. I have attached my html code here.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">7AM Dashboard</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Applications <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Domains
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="goToView('Channel')">Channel</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="goToView('Claims')">Claims</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="goToView('Member')">Member</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="goToView('Plan')">Plans</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="goToView('Provider')">Provider</a>

            <!-- <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>-->
          </div> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="d-inline-flex"><a class="nav-link " aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Date
          </a>
          <input type="date" (change)="changeDate()" [(ngModel)]="date"></div>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your nav inside a container-fluid, and add this to your css just in case:

```
html,body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;`enter code here`
            height: 100%;
    };
```

Btw, sometimes chrome does that! if you inspect/open your "yourFileName".html using Firefox it should behave properly.